# Why the Loaded event of UserControl has not called, while making the UserControl visible dynamically from collapsed state

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, user-controls

I am having an usercontrol.Intially i am collapsing the visibilty of that control.Once I make the control visible , the loaded event of the control is not getting called

Answer (score 4):

The [Loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.110).aspx) event is not raised when you change UserControl's Visibility property.
You can use [IsVisibleChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisiblechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

A useful remark about setting `Visibility` property and `IsVisibleChanged` event from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Setting this property affects the value of `IsVisible`, which in turn may raise the `IsVisibleChanged` event. However, `IsVisible` has other factors that influence it, for instance the visibility settings of parents that contain it.